# How to prevent refresh of a Superset dashboard when opening it

Tags: caching, apache-superset

I'm new to Superset and I don't know how to prevent my dashboard from refreshing every time it is opened.

I don't need it because in the database I'm using the data is inserted once a day and I've set the auto refresh interval to 24 hours. Also, the queries are quite complex so the charts take quite a long time to load.

I've searched the docs and found nothing about this issue.

Comment: What about [chaching](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/cache/)?

Answer (score 0):

A default installation of SuperSet does not have caching enabled by default. You should enable caching so that a query is not fired everytime the dashboard is viewed. It's possible to define global level caching strategy and also have dashboard specific overrides.

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/cache